# What is the cost of production or sale of a Soyuz spacecraft?

Tags: soyuz-spacecraft, cost, manufacturing

[Soyuz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_(spacecraft)) manned spacecraft have been operating for over fifty years and have made one hundred and forty five flights.  There have been many upgrades and improvements and is still going strong.  I imagine that experience and economies of scale mean that Energia, the manufacturer, can churn out the spacecraft at a low cost by now, [even though it takes three years to complete an individual spacecraft](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/29458/why-does-it-take-three-years-to-manufacture-a-soyuz-spacecraft).  Is there a published unit cost of production or sale (by Energia to Roscosmos) of a contemporary Soyuz capsule?

Comment: Soyuz spacecraft is about half reusable. The most expensive parts of the structure are reused. Therefore, there is a difference in price between completely new and using old parts.

Comment: @A.Rumlin  Thanks very much, I didn't know that.  A quick search on here reveals that 65 items in a Soyuz capsule are reusable - https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/18092/what-happens-to-soyuz-reentry-capsules-after-landing

Comment: The *descent module* may be reusable, but the orbital and service modules are discarded during re-entry, and new ones need to be added for another mission.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably all that can be found is the total value of the contract - USD35,575,564

> Договор на выполнение работ по изготовлению и сборке отсеков, сборке, проведению работ на КИС и сдаче ТПК «Союз МС», дооснащению ТПК «Союз МС» индивидуальным снаряжением (три комплекта) в соответствии с документацией Генерального конструктора на ТПК «Союз МС», подготовке к запуску ТПК «Союз МС», участию в пуске РКН и послеполётному обслуживанию СА ТПК «Союз МС» по твердой цене **2 134 533 842, 00 руб.**, со сроком начала выполнения работ - 01 апреля 2019 г, окончания работ -15 апреля 2022 г.
> page 186 https://www.energia.ru/ru/corporation/info/gosa-2020/inf07.pdf
>
> Contract for the manufacture and assembly of compartments, assembly, work at the control and test station and delivery of the Soyuz MS manned transport vehicle, retrofitting the Soyuz MS manned transport spacecraft with individual equipment (three sets) in accordance with the General Designer documentation on Soyuz MS manned transport spacecraft, preparation for launch Soyuz MS manned transport spacecraft, participation in the launch of the launch vehicle and post-flight servicing of the descent vehicle Manned transport spacecraft Soyuz MS at a fixed price of RUB 2,134,533,842.00, with start date of work - April 01, 2019, completion of work - April 15, 2022

Comment: Does the contract include launch?

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys No. "participation in the launch"

Comment: +1  If there's no better breakdown of costs by tomorrow I'll accept this.  TBH I wouldn't be surprised if Energia didn't release it cost of production for commercial reasons.

Comment: @DaveGremlin Probably a trade secret. I have met discussions where the cost of production was called less than half of the indicated amount.

Comment: @A.Rumlin +1 It would be quite normal in most countries to find the difference between cost and price being hidden though as you mention "production" it sounds as if it perhaps doesn't necessarily include costs at the launch site or perhaps even the launch vehicle. This isn't just nit-picking, it is very hard to compare launch costs when every national administration aportions costs differently into different industrial contracts, some running the launch vehicle, some the launch site operations and some to the spacecraft.

Comment: @Puffin In Soviet production, it is more of a service than a production. The customer places an order for the astronaut launch service. The executor of the order provides the spacecraft and its service support from the beginning to the end of the mission.